# Irreducibility of polynomial $x^3-y^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I was told that

> $x^3-y^2$ is irreducible in $\Bbb C[x,y]$.

But I cannot really give a sounding argument.  I supposed that it may be factored as $g_1, g_2$, and considered those monomials divisible by $y$. But possible cancellations makes it hard.

---

EDIT: Thoughts:

Suppose $(x^3-y^2)$ is reducible in $k[y][x] \cong k[x,y]$, then it would factorize as a polynomial in $x$ over the ring $k[y]$. As the degree is $3$, there must exists a monomial factorization. Hence there is a polynomial solution $x=P(y)$, which is impossible.

Comment: Your thoughts are correct. Another way is to factorize it in $k[x][y]$ and observe that $4x^3$ is not a square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*A variant* :

It is equivalent to show $y^2-x^3$ is irreducible. If it were not, it would factor as the product of two linear factors in $y$: $(y-p(x))(y-q(x))$. Expanding, we obtain by identification
$$p(x)q(x)=-x^3, \qquad p(x)+q(x)=0,$$
whence $p(x)^2=x^3$, which is impossible for degree reasons.